# OpenGL generating rectangles in Tao Framework C#

Tags: c#, opengl, frameworks, tao-framework

I am generating rectangles with given random numbers in this class.

```
class Rect
{
     double x;
     double y;

    public Rect(double _x, double _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;

    }
    public void Draw()
    {
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
        Gl.glVertex2d(x + (-0.05d), y + (-0.05d));  
        Gl.glVertex2d(x + (-0.05d), y + (0.05d));     
        Gl.glVertex2d(x + (0.05d),  y + (0.05d));          
        Gl.glVertex2d(x + (0.05d),  y + (-0.05d));     
        Gl.glEnd();

    }
}
```

I call it in Paint function.

```
        private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
          Gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
          Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
              rand = new Random();
              double x = 2 * rand.NextDouble() - 1;
              double y = 2 * rand.NextDouble() - 1;

              rect= new Rect(x,y);
              rect.Draw(); 
            }
        }
```

Everything looks fine but there is something wrong. I cant see the all rectangles. Some of them are missing. But if I toggle breakpoint somewhere or put the `MessageBox.Show(x+" "+y);` code works fine and shows me the number of rectangles what i want. I think my code is true but something wrong about OpenGL. I am using Tao Framework.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you're showing, so there isn't really enough information to do more than guessing. Is it always complete rectangles that are missing? You're seeing just 1, 2 or 3 rectangles instead of 4? The only slightly worrying thing I see in the code is that you'll need to use `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` if your rendering surface has a depth buffer.

Comment: You should flush the GL pipeline or swap buffers (implicit flush) at some point, otherwise GL can queue up all of these commands and execute them whenever it feels like it instead of when you logically expect it to happen (at the end of `simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint`).

Comment: I've added `Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` but there is no difference I see always 1 or 2 rects. I tried to `simpleOpenGlControl1.SwapBuffers()` and  `Gl.glflush()` at the end of the function but there is no change.

Comment: Tried swapbuffers in the loop but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the problem is with this bit of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    rand = new Random();
    double x = 2 * rand.NextDouble() - 1;
    double y = 2 * rand.NextDouble() - 1;

    rect= new Rect(x,y);
    rect.Draw(); 
}
```

You are creating a new `Random` instance in every iteration of your loop and then use that instance to generate two random values. The sequence of values generated by `Random` depends on the *seed* that was used to initialize the `Random`. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the constructor used here:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite
>   resolution.

That is, if your loop runs fast enough, the different instances of `Random` in your loop will be initialized with the *same seed*, causing them to generate the same `x` and `y` values: the rectangles then overlap and appear to be missing. This also explains why your code is working if you interrupt it using breakpoints or messages boxes.

**Edit**: the best solution to this problem is to create a single `Random` instance outside  of your loop, by initializing `rand` before your `for` statement or (as a class member) in the constructor of your class for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use `Thread.Sleep(100);` function and my problem solved. Big thanks :)

Comment: That's a creative workaround, but not the best :-) I've updated my answer with a better solution to the problem.

Comment: :) Thank you. You are right. There is no neep Sleep(); function :) Thats the more logical solution for this problem.